Can I try to attack(simulation) the local blocks I create on Ganache to analyze the chage of the flow?
As title, I want to make a project like that. I may use HOIC to do the simulation attack. And write a monitor code to check the unormal flow when attack. Then do some analysis or drfense. Is that legal and can be done? That
Sorry for my poor English...
Thanks!!
I'm expecting to make a simple monitor and maybe can defend the DDoS on blockchain system

And it's my first time asking question here, if there is anything unproperly, just tell me. Thanks!

Welcome to Stack Overflow, if you have a question about coding, post the code to be fixed, otherwise this is probably the wrong stack.  But DDoS can all be mitigated through 3rd party cloud services these days for the most part.
